# Finding the volume of an elliptical cone with double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For my class I need to find the volume of an elliptical cone bounded by $ z=\sqrt{9x^2+y^2} $ and the plane $z=2$. My thought process was to integrate the equation for $ z=\sqrt{9x^2+y^2} $ over the region bounded by the projection onto the xy-plane. This is the integral I set up:

$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\frac13\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\frac13\sqrt{4-y^2}} \sqrt{9x^2+y^2} \,dx\,dy$

To check my answer, I looked up and found that the volume of an elliptical cone can be found using the equation: $ V = \frac13 \pi abh $

When I checked my answer I got from the double integral, I found that it is 4 times what it should be. Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong? I cannot seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The volume integral should be,

$$V=\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\frac13\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\frac13\sqrt{4-y^2}} \left(2-\sqrt{9x^2+y^2}\right) \,dx\,dy$$

Note that the volume specified in the problem is between the elliptic cone the plane $z=2$. Your integral expression is for the volume between the cone and the plane $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand my mistake now. Do you know of a way to change the order of integration or something like that to make this integral more doable?

Comment: @NicholasMarks - You're welcome. Switching the integration order between $x$ and $y$ won't help that much, which would result in basically the same integral. It may be somewhat easier if you set up the integral in cylindrical coordinates to allow certain separability of variables.

Comment: I tried converting to cylindrical coordinates but I ended up with sqrt(8cos^2(theta)+1) which does not seem like a solvable integral to me.